# How to add script tags to head and at end of the body html.js?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm new to gatsby. I have model setup in the contentful that provides me the scripts that I wanted to add to the head or at end of the body. Now the one way of doing it is Gatsby SSR API(setPostBodyComponents).

But the thing is how can I run graphl query in gatsby-ssr? Is is valid to fetch data from contentful in this file? My concern is to add whatever scripts the contentful admin drops into model into the html.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for this is using `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-react-helmet/

That way you can add script tags just like in HTML:

```
<Helmet>
    <script src="...">
</Helmet>
```